# Securely finding hashed API key in database

Tags: security, api-key

Looking at the best practices in terms of storing API keys, how is it possible to hash the key and still allow the user to view it themselves. If an email is used to encrypt/decrypt (as a salt) with a secret on the server, how would it be possible for a user to provide an API key (say in a POST request) and find the match in the database without also providing the email.

If an API key is hashed the same as a password, it won't be accessible for the user, which would be ideal instead of having to refresh the key if it is ever forgotten.

In essence, what would be the most secure way (since nothing can ever be 100% secure) to store an API key that would still allow a user to view it if needed, and also be able to query the database using the raw key as a where clause?

For what it's worth, I'm using MongoDB with Prisma (inside Next.js api routes).

Comment: Q: how is it possible to hash the key and still allow the user to view it themselves?  A: It's easy to view the hash ... and it should be *IMPOSSIBLE* to view the original value.  Your "hash" is an example of [one-way encryption](http://www.aspencrypt.com/task_password.html).  If you want to be able to *retrieve* the original password (or *ANY* plaintext value, including the "secret" portion of an API key) - then you'll need a different encryption mechanism.

Comment: Based on some of the info I mentioned, what alternative encryption method would you recommend? Is there a best practice (or would it just be one way)?

Comment: Q: Why do you need anything besides "one-way"?  If it works: the user is authenticated.  If it doesn't work: the user needs a new key.  As far as "alternative encryption method": anything that meets your requirements. 
 AES_ENCRYPT()/AES_DECRYPT() are popular if you're using MySQL...  Look here for MongoDB: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/ClientEncryption.encrypt/

Comment: That still raises the question, how would you find user by API key if the API key hashed? Seems fairly resource intensive to compare each API key sent by the user with the hashed version, no?